# console.log called in order -> executes out of order

Tags: javascript, console.log

I got a little problem.

```
m1 = new Matrix3D(null);

m1.initRotX(20);

console.log(m1);

m1.initRotY(20);

console.log(m1);
```

this is logging 2 times the same matrix.(the y rot Matrix)
when i initialize a new matrix every time it works fine.

Is js threading this and the init function is faster the the log or is there another explenation for this?

Answer (score 1):

If you `log` an object to the console, you will see two things: one row (usually printed in italics), which shows the result of the object's `toString()` method at the moment when you called `console.log()`. The second row, which you can expand to view the detailed properties of the object, always shows the *latest* state of the object, no matter at what point the log was made.